# Wifi activity shows it's always on even though it's not on

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, tasker

check out this screenshot i just made:

[image]

Why is the Wi-fi activity bar blue for the last 25 minutes, when my wi-fi was off for 23 minutes?

i have tasker which is set to turn off wi-fi when the phone's screen is locked. I know for sure it works because if I press the power button to turn on screen (but leave it locked) there's no wifi status icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A credible source: [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/06/29/apk-teardown-android-4-3s-wi-fi-is-always-on-and-always-scanning-unless-you-find-the-special-checkbox/)

tl;dr:
Google brought in an option (by default enabled!), which is a checkbox reading "Scanning always available" in WiFi -> Advanced.

The general purpose: "To improve location accuracy and for other purposes, Google and other apps may scan for nearby networks, even when Wi-Fi is off."

> To improve location accuracy

by geolocating your IP, matching it with GPS, *probably* seeing if you use a proxy

> for other purposes

IDK, peeking into your data *maybe*?

> even when Wi-Fi is off

why is there a Wi-Fi **switch** then?

Given, that Google has *not* a reputation for invading the privacy of users a bit too much, that is/was the general motive.

As said; you can turn this somewhat *useless* feature off (hopefully); and get some more battery life on your phone.

P.S. The fact that this option is not *explicitly* stated to the user when he/she begins to use the phone, and that this option is *significantly* hidden, concerns me.

Comment: yep that was it :(

Answer (score 1):

Check whether these options as below:

Go to Settings->Wifi->Advance Settings

1)Keep WI-Fi on during sleep - Never.
2)Scanning always available  - Unchecked.
3)Wi-Fi optimization - Checked.

And then try...if that doesn't solve it can be a problem with ROM/Kernel.